# extJS: set 'config options' on field by JS

Tags: javascript, json, extjs4, extjs

why i can't set '**Config options**' by methode SET

```
set({value: 'new value',disabled:true});
```

how i can set 'Properties' for a field

```
var name = {
    fieldLabel:'Name',
    value: 'Test',
    id:'id-name',
    xtype: 'textfield',
};
this.form= new Ext.FormPanel({
    items:[name],
    buttons: [{
        text   : 'set value',
        handler: function() {
            Ext.getCmp('id-name').set({value: 'new value',disabled:true});
        }]
});
```

Comment: Configs are used during object construction, to instruct ExtJS how to create an instance of the component. Which part of your code doesn't work exactly? Giving an object as a config, or the set method within the handler?

Comment: when i set **value** by methode **Ext.getCmp('id-name').set** , dont change the value of field
how i can set 2 or more properties by json
i can only change value by **Ext.getCmp('id-name').setValue()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting component properties using an object is not part of the design of Extjs.  The config is used in object creation and when first used in the constructor is applied to the object itself using special methods from the Extjs class system core to generate getters and setters and then initialize the component from them.  It is not possible to do what you are trying to do and get the desired result.  In your example above, the textfield is initialized with your config overriding the default values of the component during creation and then it generates getters and setters for certain attributes, like value, id, and fieldLabel which need to be used instead of config objects after a component is created.  To make your example work, you need to do this:

```
var name = {
    fieldLabel:'Name',
    value: 'Test',
    id:'id-name',
    xtype: 'textfield',
};
this.form= new Ext.FormPanel({
    items:[name],
    buttons: [{
        text   : 'set value',
        handler: function() {
            var myTextField = Ext.getCmp('id-name');
            myTextField.setValue('new value');
            myTextField.setDisabled(true);
        }]
});
```